# Accurate document counts in terms aggregations with elastic search

Tags: count, elasticsearch, document, aggregation

I need the exact count of terms aggregations and I saw that elastic search [is not always accurate](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts). I wonder if there is another solution to overcome this constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set **size** to 0 in the aggregation query:

```
{
  "aggs" : {
    "products" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "product",
            "size" : 0
        }
    }
  }
}
```

But as per the documentation:

> It is possible to not limit the number of terms that are returned by setting size to 0. Don’t use this on high-cardinality fields as this will kill both your CPU since terms need to be return sorted, and your network.

Comment: it doesn't work anymore ES 5.4 - it'll `throw IllegalArgumentException("[size] must be greater than 0. Found [" + size + "] in [" + name + "]")` at least from the Java API side